# Angular 6 and PSQL Pagination response error

Tags: javascript, angular, psql

First problem: Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Second problem before that was, that the service send the request to the backend with (pagesize and offset) parameters but the backend didn't send back any data..

**Component:**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    // this.getAllEventLogs(this.eventlogs);
          this.sourceLoggercontrol.getAllEventLogs(this.pageSize, this.pageIndex)
            .subscribe(response => {
              this.eventlogs = response.eventlogs;
              this.totalItemsCount = response.totalItemsCount;
            });
            console.log(this.eventlogs)
          }

onPage(pageEvent: PageEvent): void {
    this.pageSize = pageEvent.pageSize,
      this.pageIndex = pageEvent.pageIndex;
    this.sourceLoggercontrol.getAllEventLogs(this.pageSize, this.pageIndex)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.eventlogs = response.eventlogs;
        this.totalItemsCount = response.totalItemsCount;
      });
  }
```

**SERVICE:**

```
getAllEventLogs(
            pageSize: number,
            pageIndex: number
      ): Observable<{ eventlogs: Eventlog[], totalItemsCount: number }> {
            const params = {
                  pageSize,
                  pageIndex
            }
            return this.http.get(BASE_URL + 'eventlogs', { params }) 
                  .map(res => res.json());
      }
```

**HTML:**

```
 <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="totalItemsCount" [pageIndex]="pageIndex" [pageSize]="pageSize"
          [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 15]" (page)="onPage($event)">
        </mat-paginator>
  </mat-accordion>
```

**BACKEND:**

```
function getAllEventlog(req, res, next) {
    const pageSize = req.query.pageSize;
    const pageIndex = req.query.pageIndex;
    const offset = pageSize * pageIndex;
    const limit = pageSize;
    db.any('SELECT * FROM event_log LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2', [limit, offset])
      .then(function (eventlogs) {
        return db.one('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event_log').then(countResult => {
        res.status(200)
          .json({
            eventlogs,
            totalItemsCount: countResult.count,
          });
          console.log(req.body)
        })
      })
      console.log(eventlogs)
      .catch(function (err) {
        return next(err);
      });
  }
```